# C++ typedef and templates

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, typedef

Suppose there is a tiny class

```
template<class T1>
class c {
    template<class T>
    class Test {
    public:
        typedef std::vector<T> vetor_type;

        vetor_type some_var;
    };

    void f() {
        Test<int>::vetor_type tt; //error
    }
};
```

I get an error:

> Expected ';' after expression.

Edit: I don't know why the answer about the typename was deleted, cause it actually helped.
But could someone explain why do i have to use typename if I'm writing this code inside another class template?

Comment: `Test<int>::this_type` is just the same as `Test<int>`, non?

Comment: @Kerrek SB - changed my example

Comment: It compiles fine in MSVC2010 and GCC 4.1.2.

Comment: There are no mistakes here. Please show the code before the error.

Comment: Please provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem. The code as shown compiles fine.

Comment: @givi this works perfectly now that you have edited it. What is the question again?

Comment: I'm using Apple LLVM compiler 3.0, also tried with gcc 4.2.

Comment: -1 THAT IS COMPLETELY DIFFERENT! Your typedef was Test<T> inside template Test, and it is now vector<T>!

Comment: @kol sorry, it's my mistake. I've tested it inside another class template. And there I get an error. I thought it was irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, no problem. Removed the -1.

Comment: now this one works fine with a posted and deleted answer, use `typename`

Comment: @yi_H Yeah, with `typename`, it works for me, too.

Comment: @kol but why do I have to use it when inside the class template ?

Comment: You must explicitly tell the compiler that `Test<int>::vetor_type` is a type. See Stroustrup's book, Appendix C, section 13.5.

Comment: Even after the edit, let me remark that the original class didn't make any sense at all, since it was essentially `class Box { Box x; };`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - I agree with you that this class is very synthetic and has no sence. But it actually shows the problem that I met when tried to use the std::vector iterator inside my template class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Test<T>` is dependent on the type used to instantiate `c<T1>` with so you need to use `typename` in the definition within `foo()`.

```
void f() {
    typename Test<int>::vetor_type tt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.. as it is that code looks good to me.

There's a possible **typo**: maybe **vetor_type** is in one place and **vector_type** somewhere else ?